# Error when connecting to remote sql database from service, but can from other apps

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, windows-services, remote-server

We moved our database to a separate server where it was on the same server as the web, api, couple of console apps and a windows service (msmq, rhino)

All of the above, other than the service can connect to the database just fine.

However the service (rhino service bus, consuming messages) gives an "Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed." error when trying to make a database connection.

Things I tried
* Various connection strings (btw, use an ip address for the server, but like I said this work fine with other apps)
* Running the service as Network Service, Local System, Administrator
* Configuring MSDTC on both app (old server) and db (new server with database).  Do not know anything about MSDTC, but followed the "help" if found online.
* Comment out all code in the service, only trying to open a connection (for in case a problem with the code)

All of the above resulted in exactly the same error.

Really desperate here.  Late evening and all supposed to run fine in the morning..  :-(

Comment: for what it matter, I can connect from sql management studio, to the database on the new server without problems.

Comment: I have seen this error when connecting to remote services and when I use MSDTC. I strongly believe the issue is with MSDTC. MSDTC is a service to facilitate Distributed Transaction among applications and also across servers. I will insist you to check the MSDTC settings in both the servers again. 1) Both servers must have MSDTC started in Services. 2) Database server's MSDTC should support remote connections in MSDTC properties. I will get the details in the answer section shortly. Meanwhile can you please check these again?

Comment: Let me make my question a bit more shorter. When you setup DTC, did you try setting up the Local DTC Properties in Administrative Tools?

Comment: That's correct.  (fyi: the "app server" is 2008, the "db server" 2012)

Comment: Compnent Services => Computers => My Computer => Distributed Transaction Coordinator => Local DTC => Right Click, Properties => Security Tab
Network DTC Access, Allow Remote Clients, Allow Remote Admin, Allow Inbound, Allow Outbound, No Auth Required, Enalble XA Transacions, Enable SNA ... Transactions
Logon Account is NetworkService

Comment: Thanks so much Martin, you put me on the right track.  I went and set everything on the app server as set on the db server (my previous comment) and it work!!!!

Comment: Please mark below answer if you are happy with it. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Compnent Services => Computers => My Computer => Distributed Transaction Coordinator => Local DTC => Right Click, Properties => Security Tab. Enable the settings as in the screenshot in both the servers.

[image]